# How to add elif statement to all if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Write a program that takes a date as input and outputs the date's season. The input is a string to represent the month and an int to represent the day.

Ex: If the input is:

April
11
the output is:

Spring
In addition, check if the string and int are valid (an actual month and day).

Ex: If the input is:

Blue
65
the output is:

Invalid

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month == ('March'):
    if 20 <= input_day <= 31:
        print('Spring')
if input_month == ('April' or 'May'):
    if 1 <= input_day <= 31:
        print('Spring')
if input_month == ('June'):
    if 0 <= input_day <= 20:
        print('Spring')   
if input_month == ('June'):
    if 21 <= input_day <= 30:
        print('Summer')
if input_month == ('July' or 'August'):
    if 1 <= input_day <= 31:
        print('Summer')
if input_month == ('September'):
    if 0 <= input_day <= 21:
        print('Summer')
if input_month == ('September'):
    if 22 <= input_day <= 30:
        print('Autumn')
if input_month == ('October' or 'November'):
    if 1 <= input_day <= 31:
        print('Autumn')
if input_month == ('December'):
    if 0 <= input_day <= 20:
        print('Autumn')
if input_month == ('December'):
    if 21 <= input_day <= 31:
        print('Winter')
if input_month == ('January' or 'February'):
    if 1 <= input_day <= 31:
        print('Winter')
if input_month == ('March'):
    if 0 <= input_day <= 19:
        print('Winter')
else: 
    input_month != 'January' or input_month != 'February' or input_month != 'March' or input_month != 'April' or input_month != 'May' or input_month != 'June' or input_month != 'July' or input_month != 'August' or input_month != 'September' or input_month != 'October' or input_month != 'November' or input_month != 'December'
    print('Invalid')
if 0 >= input_day >= 32:
    print('Invalid')
```

I keep getting the output as

```
Spring
Invalid
```

when it should just be the season

Comment: There are far too many comparisons here. You only need to compare the selected date to check whether it is between the start and end date for each season.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to combine two conditions using logical `or` operator.

```
if x == "something" or x == "another thing":
```

Or you can use `in` operator instead

```
if x in [str1,str2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could organize this. I think the simplest would be to group the conditions based on the output they need to produce. In other words, the line `print("Spring")` should only appear once:

```
if ((input_month == "March" and 20 <= input_day <= 31)
or  (input_month == "April" and 1  <= input_day <= 30)
or  (input_month == "May"   and 1  <= input_day <= 31)
or  (input_month == "June"  and 1  <= input_day <= 20)):
    print("Spring")
elif ((input_month == "June"      and 21 <= input_day <= 30)
or    (input_month == "July"      and 1  <= input_day <= 31)
or    (input_month == "August"    and 1  <= input_day <= 31)
or    (input_month == "September" and 1  <= input_day <= 21)):
    print("Summer")
# more elifs here
else:
    print("Invalid")
```